# How to set up a connection between spring boot project and PostgresSQL DB

Tags: spring-boot, pgadmin-4

I created a spring boot project and I link it with my DB under PgAdmin.
I've modified the application.properties correctly and created a class named "user" and its repository "userRepository" but I don't know if this will automaticly create the user table in the DB (I used annotations) or I have to create it in PgAdmin ?
Do I need to specify any controller or webController if I want to have Crud operations ? And where does the CrudRepository exists do I need to generate it and how ?

Excuse me this my first experience with spring, I will really appreciate if you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:
*I don't know if this will automaticly create the user table in the DB*

You have several ways how to create your tables, for example with property in application.properties file
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = [none|validate|update|create-drop]

where *none* means this configuration not affect existing database

*update* means updating changes in database

*create-drop* means creating all tables from scratch according your project entities classes.

You can check this documentations for additional information
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

**59.2 Initialize a database using Hibernate**

also you can check how to initialize database with existing sql scripts files in documentation above

**59.3 Initialize a database using Spring JDBC**

For question: *Do I need to specify any controller or webController if I want to have Crud operations ? And where does the CrudRepository exists do I need to generate it and how ?*

Yes you should create controllers to handle requests and repositories to work with JPA.I also suggest check tutorial first, for example this one (first in google)
https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-crud-rest-api/